# How to separate code in different controllers but provide clear URLs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I have two logical parts of this application - user part and admin panel. I don't have much experience in developing projects at all so when I was thinking about how to structure my code I decided not to use areas since they would be another thing to learn besides many other that I had to but now I face a problem.

When an user with rights enter into `www.mysite.net/admin` I want to have urls like `www.mysite.net/admin/Documents` which already leads to a problem - I have `AdminController` full of methods and even so I haven't solved even the `URL` problem because `www.mysite.net/Admin/Documents` is pretty clean, but if I want to create new `Document` because I keep all the CRUD methods inside the same `AdminController` I can't have simply `Create` method but at best `DocumentCreate` which leads to `URL` like `www.mysite.com/Admin/DocumentCreate` instead of something clear for the user (and me) like `www.mysite.com/Admin/Document/Create` and also - keeping everything in just one controller already makes it very difficult to maintain and I only will have to add more methods.

How I can both - separate the logic and not keep everything in the `AdminController` and provide clean `URLs` like the one above - `www.mysite.com/Admin/Document/Create`

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "`ActionName`" attributes and use it in your method to change the name of your action method for clean URLs
Ex.

```
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult DocumentCreate()
{
}
```

Another option to separate out the logic and maintainability, Area is the best choice.

Comment: don't you think OP has to use AREA in asp.net mvc...http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project

Answer (score 1):

The best, and probably simplest way, would be to use areas.  They're not difficult to learn so you should be able to pick it up in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to Create Area..

right click on project => add new item => Area .. give it name ADMIN

it means all your admin related code lies inside this area..

go to controllers folder and create Controller named Document and inside Create Action  method named Create and others...

url to visit : www.mysite.com/Admin/Document/Create

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project